# What is the equivalent of the following Visual C++ build options in CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I want to know how I can set the following Visual Studio build options in my CMakeLists.txt.

- Optimization = Custom (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization)
- Inline Function Expansion = Default (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization)
- Struct Member Alignment = 1 Byte (/Zp1) (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation)

Comment: You'd better mention where this properties come from (it seems that these are from some IDE) and what is their exact meaning for the build process.

Answer (score 4):

As the availability of optimization options varies from compiler to compiler, CMake does not offer a unified way of setting them for a project. You can however specify flags manually:

```
if(MSVC)
    # consider adding some additional version checks
    # enable warning level 4 and warnings-as-errors everywhere
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4 /WX")
endif()
```

Note that setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is a very crude mechanism for giving additional compile flags and should only be used if you are certain that the flags are applicable to all targets on all configurations of the project.

Since this is most certainly not the case for the flags you asked for in the question, consider using [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_compile_options) or the [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aCOMPILE_OPTIONS) target property instead.